# Integrated video card not detected after installing new video card

Tags: video, motherboard, graphics-card

I got this emachines ET1331G-03W with a built in integrated video card (GeForce 6150SE). I added another video card (e-GeForece 6200 LE) in the hopes that I utilize both and have a dual monitor. But once the additional card was installed, windows 7 does not recognize the integrated video.

Is it possible to use both video cards and have a dual monitor setup? Is there a switch on the motherboard that I have to turn on or off to enable the integrated video card along with the new card.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to go into the BIOS to find out.  Check your system documentation to determine how to enter the BIOS at boot-up.  From my experience, most BIOSes disable onboard video by default when you install a video card.

Comment: I'm guessing you found out how to turn on both video cards.